# jQuery - each() on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a `each()` on a cloned element,

```
var html = $(this).clone().html();

html.find('.class').each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('class-to-remove');             
});

console.log(html);
```

but when I see `var html` in console then it shows the previous value, not the value after `each()` was done.

Please tell me how to get var where the `each()` was done.

Comment: sidenote: you don't need the .each() method here, you can just call `html.find('.class').removeClass('class-to-remove')`

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky there are more code inside `.each()`. But thanks, i will keep this in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `.html()` is a **string**. You're better off not calling it at all in this case; just use the return value from `.clone()`.

```
var cloned = $(this).clone();
cloned.find('.class').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('whatever');
});

console.log(cloned.html());
```

Also note that `.html()` gets the **contents** of its operand, so the outer "shell" won't show up.